# How do I do this integral which gives 1 or 0 as answer?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Consider,

$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{t}\sin \left(\frac{c t}{2}\right) \cos (t \sin (\phi )) \, dt
$$

Numerical integral shows that the result is 1 when $c>2|\sin(\phi)|$ and 0 otherwise, Mathematica also says the same thing.

How do I see this analytically?

Comment: Another way to formulate this is that $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\sin(\omega_1 t)\cos (\omega_2 t)\,dt = \begin{cases} 0, & \omega_1<\omega_2 \\ 1, &\omega_2<\omega_1\end{cases}$$
for positive $\omega_1,\omega_2$. (The behavior for negative values can then be inferred from the parities of sine and cosine.) This in turn suggests using the product-to-sum formula to reduce this the identity $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\sin t \,dt=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found from the product-to-sum trig identity
$$
2\sin a \cos b = \sin(a + b) + \sin(a-b)
$$
and the well-known integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\sin(k x)\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sgn}(k),
$$
where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is $1$ for positive $k$, $-1$ for negative $k$, and $0$ for $k = 0$. Using those in the original integral gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty }\sin \left(\frac{c t}{2}\right) \cos \left[t \sin (\phi )\right]\frac{dt}{t} &=& \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\int_0^\infty \sin\left(\left[\frac{c}{2}+\sin\phi\right]t\right)\frac{dt}{ t}+ \int_0^\infty \sin\left(\left[\frac{c}{2}-\sin\phi\right]t\right)\frac{dt}{t}\right]
\\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\left[\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{c}{2}+\sin\phi\right)+\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{c}{2}-\sin\phi\right)\right].
\end{eqnarray}
You can then work out the cases to get
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty }\sin \left(\frac{c t}{2}\right) \cos \left[t \sin (\phi )\right]\frac{dt}{t} = \operatorname{sgn} c\cdot\begin{cases}1 &  |c| > 2|\sin\phi|\\ \frac{1}{2} & |c| = 2|\sin\phi|\\0 & |c| < 2|\sin\phi|\end{cases}.
$$